# How can I tell tcolorbox to not repeat the overlay when the box breaks?

Tags: tcolorbox, typography

I am trying to find a way to have a "header" of sorts as an overlay to a `tcolorbox`. It cannot just be a title. I want this overlay to only appear on the first part of a `breakable` box, and not the rest.

My minimal working example is below, and the red text repeats on the right column, while it shouldn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\newtcolorbox{test}{
  skin=enhanced,
  breakable,
  overlay={
        \node[color=red] at (frame.north) {This shouldn't repeat};
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{test}
\lipsum
\columnbreak
\lipsum
\end{test}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `overlay first=`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that almost worked! It looks great in broken boxes, but now when a box happens not to break, it has no overlay at all.

Comment: check the various overlay keys in the documentation, tcolorbox has a large number for all sort of combinations.

Comment: True enough! I had missed the existence of `overlay unbroken`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For your case, i think you sholud use `overlay unbroken and first`.